# ¿Cómo llenar datos en un datagrid en vb 6.0?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, datagrid, vb6

Estoy tratando de llenar el DataGrid con datos de un procedimiento almacenado y me sale el siguiente error :

```
La operación no esta permitida si el objeto esta abierto
```

Script

```
Option Explicit
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strconnect As String

Private Sub cmdBuscar_Click()
frmListadoSolicitudes.Show vbModal
Call obtenerListadoSolicitudes
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    strconnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=x.x.x.x; Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxx;User Id=xx;Password=xxxx"
    con.Open strconnect
    
End Sub

Private Sub obtenerListadoSolicitudes()

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "sp_listar_Sol_exp"

Set rs = cmd.Execute
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic

Set frmListadoSolicitudes.dgListadoSolicitudes.DataSource = rs

 Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Agradecería me pudieran ayudar a como resolver este problema y cual es la mejor forma de declarar la conexión ya que en varios ejemplos he visto que usan modulo. Es la primera vez que veo temas de visual basic 6.0 y se me complica hacer un simple listado.

Comment: Dónde ocurre este error?

Comment: En esta parte del codigo cmd.ActiveConnection = con

Comment: LA conexión ya está abierta en el evento Load. Por eso te da el error. ¿PAra qué quieres esa línea de código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que comentas ocurre porque no puedes cambiar algunas propiedades o reutilizar un recordset que ya está abierto.

En la primera prueba que hice con tu código, el error da en la línea `rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic` esa línea la tienes después de abrir el recordset con `Set rs = cmd.Execute` y el error te da porque no le puedes cambiar el tipo a un recorset que está abierto.

Si cambias el orden de ese par de intrucciones el error se resuelve para la primera ejecución pero si intentas ejecutarlo por segunda vez, el error ocurrirá nuevamente pero será porque intentas reutilizar un recordset que está abierto.

Mi sugerencia es que lo modifiques de la siguiente manera:

```
Private Sub obtenerListadoSolicitudes()

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_listar_Sol_exp"

    'Validar si el recordset está abierto para cerrarlo antes de volverlo a utilizar
    If rs.State = adStateOpen Then
        rs.Close 
    End If
     
    'Para abrir el recordset utiliza esta secuencia de instrucciones
    'así evitas un posible error al asignarlo al grid

    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open cmd, , adOpenStatic

    'Sugiero validar si hay resutlados antes de asignarlo al grid...

    Set frmListadoSolicitudes.dgListadoSolicitudes.DataSource = rs

    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Excelente funciono, para un insertar, actualizar, eliminar se sigue los mismos pasos.